# Filter Numpy array of tuples with vectorized access

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working with Pandas [MuliIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html). I use the [from_product](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_product) method. What I get is Numpy ndarray from the MultiIndex `values` property:

```py
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [5, 6]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df1.index, df2.index), names=['idx1', 'idx2']).values
```

It returns a Ndarray of tuples: `[(0, 0) (0, 1) (1, 0) (1, 1)]`. The problem is that **I want to keep only the tuples which both elements are equal**. But because they're tuple I can't do vectorizations like this one:

```py
equals = multi_index[multi_index[:, 0] == multi_index[:, 1]]
```

That would be possible if they were Lists instead of Tuples. Is there a way to filter by tuple's elements (could be a more complex condition than the one above)?

In case there isn't, what could I do? Cast every tuple to list? Maybe iterate over all the elements, but it would be too much slow in comparison with a vectorized solution.

Any kind of help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the dtype and shape of that ndarray of tuples?

Comment: The dtype is *object* (strings) for both elements in the tuple. The shape is variable as the DataFrames are instantiated from uploaded files by users

Comment: `np.stack(multi_index)` produces a 2d array (n,2) of integers.

Comment: Cool! I'll give a try! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add `.values` at then end so that you can call `get_level_values`

```
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df1.index, df2.index), names=['idx1', 'idx2'])
equals = multi_index[multi_index.get_level_values(0) == multi_index.get_level_values(1)]
equals
Out[487]: 
MultiIndex([(0, 0),
            (1, 1)],
           names=['idx1', 'idx2'])
```

---

For numpy array

```
idx = np.array(pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df1.index, df2.index), names=['idx1', 'idx2']).tolist())
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df1.index, df2.index), names=['idx1', 'idx2']).values
equals = multi_index[idx[:, 0] == idx[:, 1]]
equals
Out[497]: array([(0, 0), (1, 1)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for answering, this solve my problem with MultIndex, but what about filtering by Numpy array of tuples?

Comment: @Genarito you need for loop , there , since tuple ~